# How can you convert a string with the name of an array to render the array in vue.js template

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-for

```
<b-card v-for='callType in callTypes' no-body class="mb-1">
    <b-table striped hover :items="{{callType.lineType}}">
    </b-table>
</b-card>
```

When each callType is the name of an array.

```
callTypes: [mainLine, etc]
mainLine:  [firstline: number, etc etc]
```

Error: vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, Function, got String with value "mainLine".

Comment: As the error suggests: the items property is receiving a string instead of what is expecting. The value "mainLine" as the rest of your arrays, should make sense to you since there's not much in your question for us to understand; so simply as it says callType.lineType is what should be wrong as it is just a string and not the correct property you should pass.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not explaining correctly. I'm trying to use the Name of the string to extract the array with that name. So var callTypes = "mainLine" and the array called mainLine I need to render in the template.

Comment: But where is this array mainLine?

Comment: It's accessible by the template, but I need to iterate over the callTypes to grab the list/names to use in the table(loop). The several tables need to be separated by the callTypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is declared in data() then you could access it this way:

```
<b-card v-for='callType in callTypes' no-body class="mb-1">
    <b-table striped hover :items="$data[callType.lineType]">
    </b-table>
</b-card>
```